# Why am I getting System.AccessViolationException during c#/c++ dll interop?

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I am new to C# and .NET. I want to use my existing C++ dlls within .NET, so I was experimenting with interop. I don't know why this exception is raised. I know what that exception means, I read the MSDN, but not sure why that is raised.

My code is so.

The dll  code is a simple function that takes a `char*`.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)void test(char *text)
{
// these raise System.AccessViolationException
// char c = text[0]; 
// int n = strlen(text); 
// char *copy = strdup(text); 
}
```

The C# code is a simple class calling this function

```
namespace Interop_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] text = new char[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                text[i] = (char)('A' + i);
            test(text);
        }
        [DllImport("interop_test_dll.dll")]
        private static extern void test(char[] text);
    }
}
```

The said exception is raised if the commented out code in the dll function is removed. Why?

How can (or must) I pass an array of data from C# to C++?

Where can I find more information about dealing with memory management during C++/C# interop?

Answer (score 0):

Use a string and try this:

```
private static extern void test(ref string text);
```

If you want to change your string in your test function then use `ref`. Otherwise you can leave it.

Comment: This works for the code shown here, char c = text[0]; but fails for other operations like strdup, strlen etc.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put a zero at the end of the string? I think no where. I don't know if that is a problem but you can try increasing the size of of text to 11 and then putting a zero in text[10].

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  `CharSet.Ansi` and using an actual string.  Those are the keys here.

```
namespace Interop_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] text = new char[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                text[i] = (char)('A' + i);
            test(new string(text));
        }

        [DllImport("interop_test_dll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern void test(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] string text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I tried. 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'CharSet'

Answer (score 0):

These articles won't answer your specific question but they may come in useful to you as you carry on with this.

[Calling Win32 dlls in .NET with P/Invoke](https://web.archive.org/web/20120210210850/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

[Default Marshalling for value types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t2cwe11(v=vs.100).aspx)

Also, in your dllimport statements in additional to indicating the marshalling type, you can add information to indicate if they should be marshalled as input or output or both.

```
[DllImport("interop_test_dll.dll")]
private static extern void test([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr), In, Out]string text);
```